# simple Angular Component not showing up

Tags: html, angular, typescript, web

So I follow a simple YouTube beginner Tutorial for Angular.
At the start of this Tutorial it explains how to use components and I understand everything and it makes sense, but no matter what I do the component does not show up.
The code looks like this with:

app.component.html being:

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

app.module.ts being:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

header.component.html being:

```
<header> Test </header>
```

and header.component.ts being:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent {

}
```

I have no Idea why, but the header Component is not showing up if I load app.component.html. If I write normal code in app.component.html it shows up, but with this code I just get an empty side. There is also no error.

Also no other person has any Problems with this in the comments so I guess I made a mistake, but where?

I apologize for my english, I am not a native speaker and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you getting errors when building/serving the site? Are you getting a blank page? If you modify app.component.html and add content there, are you getting anything? You need to add some more information to help us help you!

Comment: @akseli I am sorry its my first question I updated it with all the details you askes for.

Comment: See the "selector" of the component, if you use as selector `app-header` you need write `<app-header></app-header>`. BTW, you can also check the officials tutorial: [tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes) and [example aplication](https://angular.io/start)

Comment: @Eliseo do you mean selector in header.component.ts ? Cause it is `app-header` and I also wrote `<app-header></app-header>` in app.component.html, what do you want me to change?

Comment: @Palaeonton, see your [component](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview#creating-a-component-manually), it's looks like `@Component{selector:'app-header',...}` Yes the "selector" is the string you indicate, as you write `app-header` to show the component need use `<app-header></app-header>` in the .html of your AppComponent

Comment: @Eliseo I just tried to change the selector to something and then I also changed the `<app-header></app-header>` part in my code to the same. For example I changed the selector to `anything` and then wrote in app.component.html `<anything></anything>` it also got auto completed by VSCode but it still didn't work.

Comment: @Palaeonton, sorry, forget my comments, I read wrong your question :( -apologies-). Your code looks like Ok. Try "re-init" the server (re-execute the ng server)

Comment: @Eliseo its ok, thanks for your help. Could you please explaine more in detail how I can re-execute the ng server I am really new to this kind of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution for my problem:
I needed to open my file in my Terminal via

```
ng serve --open
```

in the Terminal.
Before that I tried to open the file via explorer, which never worked.
As I said I am really new to this kind of programming and I have no Idea why it only works this way. So if someone could explain it to me I would be very grateful.